# How to compare types in Swift?

Tags: swift

I declare two variables in a Swift file, with the following values:

```swift
let m = 1
let n = 2
```

Now, I would like to compare their types:

```swift
type(of: m) === type(of: n)
```

The following compliling error occurs:

```
Argument type 'String.Type' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type
```

Is there a way to compare types ?

Also, why does this line fail ?

```swift
String === String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `===` operator is only defined for reference types, since it checks reference (pointer) equality, so you can't use it on metatypes of value types.

However, you can use the normal equality operator, `==`.

```
type(of: m) == type(of: n)
```

As for `String === String`, that's not even valid code. What you need if `String.self == String.self`. You can access metatypes using `TypeName.self`.

Comment: Thank you, @Dávid Pásztor ! Isn't `type(of: m) == type(of: n)` equivalent to `Int == Int` ? If that is the case, why should I do `Int.self == Int.self` ?

Comment: `Int` is not the type but the way you tell the compiler about the type of a variable, it's nothing on its own during runtime. `Int.self` is the value that represents the `Int` type.

Comment: @F.Zer no, `Int` is the type itself, but you need instances to call the equality operator on. `Int.self` returns the singleton instance of the metatype (`Int.Type`), which supports the equality operator.